# HTTPModule Issue: Replacing Text On Page Render

Tags: c#, obfuscation, httpmodule, spam-prevention

I am writing an HTTPModule that will search out all mailto links in a webpage, obfuscate the email address and trailing parameters and then place the newly obfuscated string back into the HTML document. I then use a little JavaScript to un-obfuscate the mailto link in the browser so that it will behave properly when the user clicks the link.

So far, I have successfully obfuscated and un-obfuscated the information with no problems. The issue that I am running into is the placement of the obfuscated strings back into the stream. If a mailto link only appears once in a document, then it perfectly places the obfuscated string in place of the mailto link, but if there are more than one mailto link, the placement of the strings is seemingly random. I’m pretty sure it has to do with the position of the regex match indexes as the function loops through the matches and basically increases the length of the HTML coming through the stream. I’m going to post some strategically-edited code here to see if anyone has an idea on how to correctly target the placement of the obfuscated string.

I'm also posting the work I did to obfuscate the string in the hopes that it might help someone trying to do the same thing.

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
  {
      byte[] data = new byte[count];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
      string html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

      //--- Work on the HTML from the page. We want to pass it through the 
      //--- obfusication function before it is sent to the browser.
      html = html.Replace(html, obfuscate(html));

      byte[] outdata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
      _strmHTML.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
  }


protected string obfuscate(string input)
    {

      //--- Declarations
      string email = string.Empty;
      string obsEmail = string.Empty;
      string matchedEMail = string.Empty;
      int matchIndex = 0;
      int matchLength = 0;

      //--- This is a REGEX to grab any "a href=mailto" tags in the document.
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"<a href=""mailto:[a-zA-Z0-9\.,|\-|_@?= &]*"">", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      //--- Because of the nature of doing a match search with regex, we must now loop through the results
      //--- of the MatchCollection.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {

            //--- Get the match string
            matchedEMail = match.ToString();
            matchIndex = match.Index;
            matchLength = match.Length;

            //--- Obfusicate the matched string.
            obsEmail = obfusucateEmail(@match.Value.ToString());

           //--- Reform the entire HTML stream. THis has to be added back in at the right point.
           input = input.Substring(0, matchIndex) + obsEmail + input.Substring(matchIndex + matchLength);                 
        }

      //--- Return the obfuscated result.
      return input;
    }



protected string obfusucateEmail(string input)
  {

      //--- Declarations
      string email = string.Empty;
      string obsEmail = string.Empty;

      //--- Reset these value, in case we find more than one match.
      email = string.Empty;
      obsEmail = string.Empty;

      //--- Get the email address out of the array
      email = @input;

      //--- Clean up the string. We need to get rid of the beginning of the tag, and the end >. First,
      //--- let's flush out all quotes.
      email = email.Replace("\"", "");

      //--- Now, let's replace the beginning of the tag.
      email = email.Replace("<a href=mailto:", "");

      //--- Finally, let's get rid of the closing tag.
      email = email.Replace(">", "");


      //--- Now, we have a cleaned mailto string. Let's obfusicate it.
      Array matcharray = email.ToCharArray();

      //--- Loop through the CharArray and encode each letter.
      foreach (char letter in matcharray)
      {
          //Convert each letter of the address to the corresponding ASCII code.
          //Add XX to each value to break the direct ASCII code to letter mapping. We'll deal
          // with subtracting XX from each number on the JavaScript side.
          obsEmail += Convert.ToInt32((letter) + 42).ToString() + "~";
      }

      //--- Before we return the obfusicated value, we need to reform the tag.
      //--- Remember, up above, we stripped all this out. Well now, we need 
      //--- to add it again.
      obsEmail = "<a href=\"mailto:" + obsEmail + "\">";

      return obsEmail;
  }
```

I appreciate any ideas!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: HI Mike Can u share your complete code here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you can do is use the match evaluator in your regex ....

```
protected string ObfuscateUsingMatchEvaluator(string input)
{
            var re = new Regex(@"<a href=""mailto:[a-zA-Z0-9\.,|\-|_@?= &]*"">",            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            return re.Replace(input, DoObfuscation);

}

protected string DoObfuscation(Match match)
{
       return obfusucateEmail(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your performance needs (depends on your document size among other things), you might consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of your regular expression to parse and manipulate your HTML. You can use Linq to Objects or XPath to identify all of your mailto tags.

You should be able to modify the example below (from [the codeplex wiki page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)) to find the mailto tags:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    if (att.Value.StartsWith("mailto:") EncryptValue(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: Hey Philipp, I actually did take a look at that product. There's not really enough documentation or valid samples for me to try to bring it into our environment here. We have big client sites and I can't risk issues.

Comment: @Mike added an example. The code is in a single assembly which you can deploy and reference from your project. It is widely used for these type of tasks.